# NSURLSessionConfiguration HTTPAdditionalHeaders not set

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, foundation, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Authorization header is set in `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, however it is not attached to `NSURLSessionDataTask`. Is this a bug in `Foundation framework`?

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[configuration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization":@"123"}];

// Initialize session with NSURLSessionConfiguration
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSURLSessionDataTask *sessionTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
}];

[sessionTask resume];
```

Comment: You got any solution?

Comment: this works for me smoothly (on iOS 15)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I try this in Swift and it works

```
    var sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    var xHTTPAdditionalHeaders: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["X-test":"taly"]
    sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = xHTTPAdditionalHeaders
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
```

Comment: Works for `X-test` but won't work for `Authorization`. See Dongjin Suh answer.

Comment: `config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [ "authorization": "token abcd"]` works for me smoothly (iOS 15).

Answer (score 5):

In the NSURLSessionConfiguration [document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411532-httpadditionalheaders?language=objc),

> An NSURLSession object is designed to handle various aspects of the
>   HTTP protocol for you. As a result, **you should not modify the
>   following headers**:
>
> **Authorization**
>
> Connection
>
> Host
>
> WWW-Authenticate

Comment: This doc still exists in 2021, but the instructions re: Authorization field seem to be irrelevant.