# Sending custom HTTP headers in swift

Tags: json, swift

I managed to fetch json from my server but now I want to add extra security by way of http headers.  This is how my code barely looks like for now:

```
let urlPath = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if ((error) != nil) {
                println("Error")
            } else {
                // process json
                let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                println(jsonResult["user"])
            }
        })
```

The headers that I want to add to this request are the following:

- uid, which holds an integer value
- hash, which is a string

If it helps, I have another app built in Titanium framework which uses this syntax:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('uid', userid);
xhr.setRequestHeader('hash', hash);
```

So, am basically looking for a Swift equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLSessionConfiguration HTTPAdditionalHeaders not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751768/nsurlsessionconfiguration-httpadditionalheaders-not-set)

Comment: @Abizern how can that question be a duplicate for this question? That one is for objective-c isn't ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan the answer is in Swift and answers this question.

Comment: @Abizern that doesn't make any sense. I ask in Jave and a question comes in Python. POOM accepted answer

Comment: Did you check my answer please ?

Comment: You might want to have look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041654/how-can-i-define-content-type-in-swift-using-nsurlsession/27042176#27042176)

Answer (score 4):

You are using `dataTaskWithURL` while you should use `dataTaskWithRequest`, that takes `NSMutableURLRequest` object as an input. Using this object you can set HTTP headers, HTTPBody, or HTTPMethod

```
        let urlPath = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET" // make it post if you want
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")//This is just an example, put the Content-Type that suites you
        //request.addValue(userid, forHTTPHeaderField: "uid")
        //request.addValue(hash, forHTTPHeaderField: "hash")
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
          //do anything you want
        })
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use Alamofire for networking
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

It is written in Swift and is every easy to use. Have a look at that page.

Comment: Actually i do not see the reason of your comment. Never said it was more powerful, i just found it easier to use, so i suggested to use it.

Comment: what is the reason of my comment? bty it is not me who downvotes, and I am checking the library, it is nice, but i always prefer to go with native

Comment: It's a cool library and well supported by the community. Give it a try next time you need networking 